# База mongodb распухает после восстановления из дампа

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb, dump

Есть mongo версии 4.0.6 установленная на ubuntu server 16.04.
При восстановлении базы из дампа происходит увеличение ее объема, примерно раза в два. С чем может быть связан такой забавный глюк и как с ним бороться ?
Помимо прочего было замечено еще, что время от времени база начинает пухнуть после рестарта. В логах ничего подозрительного не наблюдается.

Comment: В чем заключается увеличение объема? И что значит "пухнуть"?

Comment: Увеличение объема заключается в приросте объема одной конкретной коллекции, которая и так занимает достаточно много места.
А пухнуть - это просто образное выражение. Извиняюсь.

Comment: т.е. данные остались те же, но база занимает больше места?

Comment: Да. Именно так.